# Concurrent update to the same collection same document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

**Problem Statement**

How do i handle concurrent update commands on same collection and same document.

**Current DB Structure**

**EDIT - Structure changed**

```
  {
     "userId":1,
     "summary_extra":[
        {
           "some_id":1,
           "names":[
              "one",
              "two"
           ]
        },
        {
           "some_id":2,
           "names":[
              "three",
              "four"
           ]
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "userId":2,
     "summary_extra":[
        {
           "some_id":1,
           "names":[
              "one",
              "two"
           ]
        },
        {
           "some_id":2,
           "names":[
              "three",
              "four"
           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

If one user tries to update at a time then there wont be any problem to update the document. But if there are more than one users(whihc is likely to 10, minimum) then how can i update same document.

What do i do in this scenarios??

N:B Datas are exact, but exact same structure i have.

**EDIT** : So now i think i can update two different documents in the same collections simultaneously by multiple users??

Comment: Categorically speaking, you must devise *some* way, either to prevent two users from updating the same document, or, if this makes sense in your situation, to permit the various updates to proceed without conflict.  You might inform the other users, "I'm sorry, but this document is being updated by someone else right now."  Otherwise, you must either have some reliable way to merge two sets of changes (no matter how "stale" one user's version of the data might now be), or else to inform them, "I'm sorry, but someone else has updated. Try again."

Comment: Key point:  your implementation has to reflect "what makes sense for the *end-user,* from *his or her* perspective."  It must be convenient, sensible, and above all, must ensure that everyone is able to clearly know what the document winds-up containing, without stepping on one another's toes or trashing the document.  Consider the "use case" very carefully, from the end-user's point of view.

Comment: If you would've posted these comments as an answer I'd give you an upvote ;)

Comment: Do you need the concurrency management on the database level?

Comment: @MikeRobinson even if two users modify the document, i am thinking, as they will be updating two different arrays inside the document. So one query might update first element in array and other might update the next element. What would you suggest??

Comment: I think that you *(a)* definitely MUST use database transactions (to achieve database-level concurrency), and that *(b)* beyond that, "it really depends upon what the business use-case is."  What *makes sense* here?  Is it "okay" for two users to be updating two different arrays within this document at the same time?  (What if their copy is "stale," so they post an out-of-date array?)  It gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You can include a version field which gets incremented with each update (it'd be one more $inc in your update and a query filter).  Then if someone has updated the document away from the version you have, no updates can go through.  If you're using Morphia, the `@Version` annotation takes care of this for you transparently.

Comment: "Versioning" is an excellent suggestion.  Instead of constantly updating *the same* record, you (within a database transaction ...) create a new *copy* of it, with an incremented "version number."  Perhaps the record also carries with it the version-number that it was created from.  Now, there's no possibility of conflict because every "updated copy" is, in fact, a *new* one ... and both the "older" and the "newest" ones are constantly available.  Even if two users did make conflicting changes, you have an accurate record of both sessions, and can *reliably* fix it (into another new version).

Comment: BTW, there are database systems, such as Firebird, which fundamentally use this technique instead of traditional "transactions."  (They *implement* "traditional transactions" in this way, but the implementation has very different concurrency effects.  Long-running report jobs with big-phat queries *don't* cause bottleneck-locks.)

Comment: Morphia's versioning doesn't create new copies of the documents though I wrote an extension that does that:  https://github.com/evanchooly/lariat

Comment: Version looks like a solution but a user with the version of current data can only update the record would be a better. Thanks.

Comment: You can do manually locking then, if you need.  Use a findAndModify where locked==false and update it to true.  If the findAndModify works, you'll have "checked out" that document.  Then update and write it back setting locked to false.  Others will fail to find that document until it's unlocked.  You'll just have to deal with any timeouts on the processes holding locks, though.

Comment: This is a very good way to achieve the desired result and has many advantages.   It does not strain the engine and great scale is possible.  It makes the fact that someone is "working" on the information explicit so that other callers can take alternate actions.   It allows for an "admin" to logically lock material.