# Prevent overload due to Promise resolving

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, bluebird

I need to perform lots of `findOneAndUpdate()` operations using mongoose as there is no way to perform an atomic operation in bulk. Therefore I create a promise array in a for loop which will be resolved afterwards. Unfortunately this takes ~2-3 seconds and during that time my Express application can't process any new requests.

**The code:**

```
const promiseArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
  const p = PlayerProfile.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updateDoc)
  promiseArray.push(p)
}
return Promise.all(promiseArray).then((values) => {
  // Process the values
})
```

**Question:**

How can I avoid that my Express application becomes completely unresponsive to new requests while it's resolving this promise?

**More context information:**

I am trying to update and return many documents with a atomic operation, hence the big for loop. It's basically selecting a document and setting up a lock for this document.

Comment: Nothing in that code *resolves* any of those promises, it just generates them (assuming a reasonable guess at what `findOneAndUpdate` does, given it returns a promise). Are you asking about a delay creating the promise array (which seems like it shouldn't take any significant time) or waiting for the resolution? If the latter, you need to show us more context...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the then, I hope that's enough context. I don't think the creation of the promise array takes that long. I am convinced (even though I haven't checked in detail) that resolving the 1500 findOneAndUpdate operations take 2-3 seconds.

Comment: Could you elaborate more what you are trying to achieve? Making 1.5k queries to DB on HTTP query shows there is something wrong with the architecture.

Comment: Unless `findOneAndUpdate` is actually doing a lot of sync things then it shouldn't block. It's a big loop though and that might just very well be the problem.

Comment: @RistoNovik I understand the impression, but what I need to do is to find and modify multiple documents with an atomic operation, so that a concurrent request would not return & modify the same document again.

Comment: But this wouldn't be atomic operation anyway when someone else runs the same HTTP query it could be the first one to modify. `In MongoDB, a write operation is atomic on the level of a single document, even if the operation modifies multiple embedded documents within a single document.`

Comment: The order of the 1500 documents doesn't matter, see the context information above. It just needs to be atomic because it would create a lock for this document. The filter checks for the set lock. Then it's impossible to select a locked document. And just to clarify even though it doesn't really matter this is just a background task for an Express application, not a route.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **update** with the **multi** option:

```
PlayerProfile.update(filter, updateDoc, { multi: true }, function(err, result) {
  // Do something
})
```

The signature is:

```
Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback)
```

Comment: That doesn't return the updated documents which is necessary for my case.

Comment: You could then use **find** with the same filter.

Comment: Then it's not atomic anymore and this is necessary as well. I've added a bit more context information into the original thread.

Comment: The docs suggest that to prevent MongoDB from inserting the same document more than once, create a unique index and use the **upsert: true** option when updating.

Comment: I am not inserting.

Comment: There is answer here which suggests adding a version field, which might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193283/concurrent-update-to-the-same-collection-same-document